# Подключение к сервисам через globalprotect

Tags: сеть, ftp, vpn, remote

У меня такая проблема, подключаюсь к впн норм, пингую сервер к которому нужно подключиться по фтп или удаленной бд, тоже все норм пингуется. Но вот если пробовать подключиться к фтп через консоль например ftp ip, то выкидывает вот это

```
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
Login failed.
No control connection for command: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

К бд когда пытаюсь подключиться показывает таймаут и не подрубается. Через mongodb compass периодически показывает что коннект прошел но логин ошибка, хотя все даннеы 100% верные. Может мне нужно что-то отключить, что-то блочит соеднение? уже второй день не могу разобраться что делать. Кто знает, прошу подскажите что можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

это проблема на стороне сервера,была блокировка не поддерживаемой системы. Так что нужно смотреть на стороне сервера.